# How to change my Heroku management command to use a worker dyno

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-scraping, dyno

I am new to all things Heroku/Django so apologies if this question is elementary. I've developed my first minor app using Django and have just deployed it into Heroku. A major part of the app is that I have a scraper that scrapes about 150K records and dumps the data into my Heroku Postgres database...it takes about 2.5 hours to run - ideally, I'd like this to run every other day but for now, that is another issue.

As of right now I have this scraper in a management command in my project and when I want to run it I manually use:

```
heroku run python manage.py scrape_data
```

I inspected my logs while this was running and noticed it is using a one-off-dyno as opposed to a worker which I read was better for long-running jobs like mine.

My question is, how can I change my Procfile (or something else) so that Heroku knows to use a worker dyno whenever I execute this task? If it's something I can add to the Heroku scheduler that'd be great to solve, though from what I understand those exclusively use one-off dynos so that is probably out of the question.

Here's my current profile:

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file -
```

I've tried reading some Heroku docs on queuing, background jobs, etc but I haven't really be able to find something that would help me. I'm wondering if it's as easy as adding something like the below to my Procfile? Then when I run the command Heroku would know to use a worker dyno to execute it?

```
worker: scrape_data.py
```

My current project structure:

```
Project
    
    -> scraper_app
        
        -> Management

            -> Commands

                -> init.py

                -> scrape_data.py

    -> home_page

        -> views.py

    -> Procfile

    -> requirements.txt

    -> manage.py

    -> runtime.txt
```

Comment: Changing the Procfile should be enough, did you try?

Comment: What would I change it to? Just worker: scrape_data.py and redeploy? Then when I run my management command in future Heroku will use the worker dyno as opposed to the one-off?